# Data is not displaying in the dynamic layout

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I want to display the text that is coming from a database in a dynamic `TextView`. I created dynamic layout as many row of the table, and I also created the `TextView` dynamically.

In the log that is mention below getting the text but it not display in the `TextView`.
Here is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(this);
    linear.setId(100+i);

    LayoutParams pram=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linear.setLayoutParams(pram);
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    for (int j = 0; j < countcolumn.size(); j++) {
        TextView view = new TextView(this);
        Log.i(ListViewDisplay.class.getSimpleName(),
                "column values that is want to set "
                + columnValues.get(j));

        String temp=columnValues.get(j).toString();

        view.setText(temp);
        view.setTextSize(20);
        view.setId(j + 11);
        view.setWidth(200);
        view.setHeight(100);
        view.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        linear.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: you add a lot of TextViews to a LinearLayout.. but do you add the LinearLayout to a parent that is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set your TextViews' `LayoutParams` for them to be drawn correctly.

Try calling this before `linear.addView(view)`:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(200, 100));
```

You can then also remove these lines, as they will be handled by the `LayoutParams`:

```
view.setWidth(200);
view.setHeight(100);
```